# How to replace \' with ' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing, python-re

I need to clean the text, which contains sequences of **`\'`**
I want to remove backslashes while keeping the single quotes. I have tried to place backslashes before backslashes and quotes, but without avail. Any advice to me?

**Code:**

```py
import re

samplestr="q\\\'q"
print(samplestr)
samplestr=re.sub("\\\'" , "\'",samplestr)
print(samplestr)
```

**Output:**

```
q\'q
q\'q
```

Comment: `"\\\'"` -> `"\\\\'"` or `r"\\'"`. The second form is called "raw string literal". Also you don't need to use backslash for quote: `"\'"` -> `"'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little confusing because you are using regex. If you use regular `replace`, your code works as is:

```
samplestr = "q\\\'q"
print(samplestr) # q\'q
samplestr = samplestr.replace("\\\'", "\'") # escape actually unnecessary for single quote
print(samplestr) # q'q
```

However, when you use `re.sub`, the first argument is treated as a *regex pattern*, not a string. So it ends up searching for a match of the *regex pattern* `\'`, which is just an escaped apostrophe. To include a literal backslash in regex you need to use `\\`.

For better readability you should use a [Python raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) by starting with `r`. Then you can do the following:

```
samplestr = re.sub(r"\\'", "'", samplestr)
print(samplestr) # q'q
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `regex` module for this.

```
samplestr = "q\\\'q"
samplestr.replace("\'", "'")
```

Will do the job. The `s.replace(a,b)` function will replace any occurence of the `character`/`string` `a` with `b` in the string `s` ie,

```
a = 'asdfgghhfdaaaaaqwwweaaa'
a.replace('a','1')
```

Output :

> '1sdfgghhfd11111qwwwe111'

In the case of `\`, you need to use `\\` because, it is an escape character.

Comment: Minor technical detail: the additional \ is not necessary because \ is an escape character, but because \ is an escape sequence. (For example, you should also escape a quote, which is not an escape character, but you don't have to escape \y, which is not an escape sequence.)

Comment: NB: I wanted to format the backslashes as code in my previous comment, but apparently SO has it's own escaping rules and now I got really confused ;-)